# The area of ​a triangle, if the vertices are complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to check for this task, if my logic is correct ?

The task is:

Complex numbers are given, which represent the points of a triangle.

$z_1=2+i$

$z_2=i$

$z_3=\lambda-2i$

$z_1$ and $z_2$ represent fixed points, while $z_3$ depends on $\lambda$.

Calculate the area of ​​the triangle

I tried this:

I took that $\lambda$ for example $1$.

$P_{\triangle z_1z_2 z_3}=\frac{1}{2}\left|\begin{vmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & -2 & 1 \end{vmatrix}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\cdot (2+1+0-(1-4+0))=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 6=3$

By taking any other number for the $\lambda$, the same result is obtained.

Can it be done in any other way?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: That looks right, but didn't you just put $\lambda$ in the determinant?  I can't follow the details of your calculation, though I agree with the answer.

Answer (score 3):

We will assume that $\lambda$ varies over the reals.

Let segment $z_{1}z_{2}$ be the base of this triangle, and note that it has length $2$. It is parallel to the real axis and has imaginary coordinate $i$.

Now note that $z_{3}$ has fixed imaginary coordinate $-2i + \text{Im}(\lambda) = -2i$, so the triangle will have base $2$ and height $3$ without regard to the value of $\lambda$. Thus, $\boxed{\triangle z_{1}z_{2}z_{3}\text{ has area }3.}$

For a general triangle, I would either use determinants or the Shoelace Formula (which is equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

On Cartesian plane, $z_1=A(2,1)$, $z_2=B(0,1)$ and $z_3=C(\lambda, -2)$ i.e., $C$ is any point on the line $y=-2$ (for real $\lambda$).

$\triangle ABC$ is a triangle with base $AB$ of length $2$ and height (distance of $C$ from horizontal line $AB$) $3$.

$$\therefore [ABC] = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 2\cdot 3 = \boxed{3}$$

It becomes clear now why the area is independent of $\lambda$. The height of triangle doesn't depend on $\lambda$ (location of $C$ on line $y=-2$).

Answer (score 0):

The area of $\triangle ABC$ in terms of the coordinates of its vertices
$(A_x,A_y)$, $(B_x,B_y)$, $(C_x,C_y)$
is  found as
\begin{align} 
S&=
\tfrac12\,|(B_x-A_x)(C_y-A_y)-(B_y-A_y)(C_x-A_x)|
,
\end{align}

so, for $A=(2,1)$, $B=(0,1)$, $C=(\lambda,-2)$

\begin{align}
S&=\tfrac12\,|(0-2)(-2-1)-(1-1)(\lambda-2)|
=3
.
\end{align}

In this case $\lambda$ vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

kludginess says hello via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula.

$$A = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)
\sqrt{4a^2b^2 - (a^2 + b^2 - c^2)^2}
.$$

$z_1 = (2+i), ~z_2 = (i), ~z_3 = (\lambda - 2i).$

$a = |z_1 - z_2| = 2.$ 
$b = |z_1 - z_3| = |(2 - \lambda) - 3i| 
= \sqrt{(\lambda - 2)^2 + 9}.$ 
$c = |z_2 - z_3| = |\lambda - 3i| = \sqrt{\lambda^2 + 9}.$

$$A = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)
\sqrt{4(2)^2(\lambda^2 - 4\lambda + 13) 
- \left[(4 + (\lambda^2 - 4\lambda + 13) - (\lambda^2 + 9)\right]^2}
$$

$$= \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)
\sqrt{4(2)^2(\lambda^2 - 4\lambda + 13) 
- \left[(8 - 4\lambda)\right]^2}
$$

$$= \sqrt{(\lambda^2 - 4\lambda + 13) 
- \left[(2 - \lambda)\right]^2}
$$

$$= \sqrt{(\lambda^2 - 4\lambda + 13) 
- \left[4 - 4\lambda + \lambda^2\right]}
$$

$$= \sqrt{(13) 
- [4]} = 3.
$$